# How can I send a DELETE request from HTML?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, salesforce

I'm making an HTML interface for a Cloudfront/S3-fronted bucket, and I want to be able to delete objects in it through that interface. I can write GET and POST requests fine to list and view objects in the bucket, but I've no idea how to write a delete request.

```
private String buildURL(String endpoint) {
    String secret    = 'some_secret';
    Datetime dt      = Datetime.now();
    Long longTime    = dt.getTime();
    Long expiryLong  = (longTime / 1000) + 10;
    String url       = 'https://' + cf + endpoint +
                       '?Prefix=' + user_id;
    String expiry    = String.valueOf(expiryLong);
    String policy    = policy(url, expiry);
    String policyEnc = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(policy));
    String rPolicy   = cfReplace(policyEnc);
    Blob mac         = Crypto.generateMac('HMACSHA1',
                                          Blob.valueOf(rPolicy),
                                          Blob.valueOf(secret));
    String signature = cfReplace(EncodingUtil.base64Encode(mac));

    return 'https://' + cf + endpoint +
           '?Prefix=' + user_id + '&Policy=' + policyEnc +
           '&Signature=' + signature + '&Key-Pair-Id=' + keyPairId;
}
```

If that's the method I use to generate a URL to view an object, how can I change it to a delete request and attach that to an `<a href...` tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use ajax.

```
<a href="test.php" onclick="sendDelete(event)">test</a>
<script>
    function sendDelete(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        xhttp.open("DELETE", this.href, true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There may not be a way to attach it to a a href object unfortunately. The elements in the form can perform only [POST and GET only.](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-method). You may have to manually construct the delete method for the header (either with form submission on the server side) or using a HTTP library to complete the operation.